# Term for the set of all reachable vertices from a vertex in a directed graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a directed graph and let $v$ be a vertex. Let $R$ be the set of all vertices that are reachable from $v$. Is there a special name either for $R$ or for the subgraph induced by $R$ ?

If the graph was undirected, I guess what I am looking for would be the connected component which $v$ belongs to.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [reachability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reachability) doesn't seem to mention such a term.

Comment: Yes, I checked it and didn't see such a term as well.

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard it called anything but "the set of vertices reachable from $v$" but I'm not an expert by any means.